# Fedora UEFI and BIOS

Tags: boot, bios, multi-boot, fedora, uefi

I am a bit confused with that BIOS/UEFI thing on Fedora. 
I have dual boot Windows 10 (on my SSD) and a freshly installed Fedora 31 Workstation (on my HDD).
 
When I check the BIOS Mode in Windows is shows 'Legacy', also my motherboard (MSI Z370-A PRO) specification shows that it has BIOS. Also, a BIOS menu title says 'MSI Click BIOS 5'. 
But when I had been installing Fedora and I had created a `/boot` partition I got a warning that I need to have `/boot/efi` partition.  So in addition to `/boot`, I created `/boot/efi` of the same size (250 MiB). 
After the installation and rebooting PC it turned out that Fedora automaticlly have changed a boot order and set `UEFI Hard Drive Fedora` on the first place.
Now when I am using Windows there is a new Local Disk (F:) (249 MB) containing `EFI` and `System` directories and `match_kernel` file. 
Apparently my BIOS can handle UEFI devices like UEFI Hard Drive, UEFI CD/DVD, UEFI Flashdrive, etc. 
Also, my SSD containing Windows 10 is not marked as a UEFI device. 
Did I do something wrong? Do I have UEFI or BIOS? And which partitioning of a free space of my HDD for Fedora is correct: `/boot`, `/boot/efi` or both?

Comment: Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI boot mode with gpt partitioning since Windows 8 released in 2012. All hardware then since 2012 is UEFI, but many vendors still call it BIOS. How you boot install media, is then how it installs. If drive is the 35 year old MBR(msdos), then you installed Windows in BIOS boot mode. UEFI requires an ESP - efi system partition.  Fedora normally installs with a separate /boot partition. You cannot have Windows in BIOS mode and any other install in UEFI mode on same drive as you can only have one boot flag per drive.

Comment: Okay, then I have UEFI on my motherboard, but it is named BIOS.
So it is good that I have Fedora in UEFI boot mode on HDD, but what with Windows 10? Is it okay to have Windows 10 in BIOS 'Legacy' mode?

Comment: Windows will work in BIOS mode, but Microsoft did not even want vendors to support BIOS mode drivers. Some many large companies still wanted compatibility with Windows 7 they allowed BIOS mode. You cannot dual boot on one drive as Windows has to have boot flag on its boot partition and UEFI requires boot flag on ESP. If two drives and separate, you may be able to dual boot, but also may have to change boot mode in UEFI/BIOS. And then cannot dual boot from grub, but only from UEFI/BIOS directly.